# Query from many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql

Student stores a list of student name and Friend stores relationship between students.

```
Create table Student (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(35),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into Student (name) values ('John');
insert into Student (name) values ('Kelly');
insert into Student (name) values ('Mary');

Create table Friend (
  id_from int NOT NULL REFERENCES Student(id),
  id_to int NOT NULL REFERENCES Student(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id_from, id_to)
);

insert into Friend (id_from,id_to) values (1, 3);
insert into Friend (id_from,id_to) values (1, 2);
insert into Friend (id_from,id_to) values (3, 2);
```

How can I query all friends of "John", for example, in MySql? The schema is here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aeacd/1

Comment: Do you have something you have tried already? In case you have where do you get lost?

Comment: Select S.name FROM Student S JOIN Friend F ON S.id=F.id_from WHERE S.name='John'. Should be something like this. But this returns two "John", not his friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a query. In general you can join tables with itself using the relation table. What the query does is join `Student` with `Friend` with `Student` and then selects the entries with `"John"` as name in the joined table between `Student.id` and `Friend.id_from.`

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student as s1
INNER JOIN Friend as f1 on s1.id = f1.id_from
INNER JOIN Student as s2 on s2.id = f1.id_to
WHERE s1.name = "John";
```

you can try it out here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aeacd/15

Comment: It's really cool. Do you think this is a good design of the database for this case?

Comment: From what i remember from my database course at the University this is the way we were taught to do it.

Comment: However, if I only want get a list of friend name, not the four columns. How to modify it? Or How do I access the name field of the friend?

Comment: As i have created table aliases in the Query you can access them by the "new names". So s2.name will reference John's friends names. S1.name will be equal to "ID_from" name. (Hope it's clear)

Comment: Great, I just tried that. And it works. Also, the "as" can be omitted in the statement. Right? Does the 'as' make any difference here?

Comment: There would be an error if the as is omitted in this case. The reason for this is that you would end up with multiple columns having the same name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105205/discussion-between-user697911-and-archifloyd).