# Modeling many-to-many Relationship in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

The schema is here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ec63/2

or here;
[Query from many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760629/query-from-many-to-many-relationship)

Now, I created the following classes:

1. Student.java

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Student implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;

   @NotNull
   @Size(min = 1, max = 35)
   private String name;

   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Friend.java

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Friend implements Serializable {

   @EmbeddedId
   @NotNull 
   @ManyToMany( targetEntity = Student.class ) 
   private FriendPK primaryKey;


   public FriendPK getPrimaryKey() {
       return primaryKey;
   }

   public void setPrimaryKey(FriendPK primaryKey) {
       this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
   }
   }
   ```
3. FriendPK.java

   ```
   @Embeddable
   public class FriendPK implements Serializable {

   @JoinColumn( name = "id_from", referencedColumnName = "id") 
   private int idFrom;

   @JoinColumn( name = "id_to", referencedColumnName = "id") 
   private int idTo;

   public FriendPK() {
   }

   public int getIdFrom() {
       return idFrom;
   }

   public void setIdFrom(int idFrom) {
       this.idFrom = idFrom;
   }

   public int getIdTo() {
       return idTo;
   }

   public void setIdTo(int idTo) {
           this.idTo = idTo;
       }
      }
   ```

1) Is this enough to model the many-to-many relationship? More specifically,

2) Do I need another "List friends" variable in Student class to store this student's friends?

3) Likewise, do I need another "List students" variable in Friend class to store students which are friends?

I vaguely feel the current design isn't enough, but can't figure out exactly what's needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Edited: The @ManytoMany annotion seems not right. How to map this many-to-many relationship in SQL to the JPA classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one entity to implement such schema. Hibernate will create a join table for `@ManyToMany` association. If you need to specify name of the join table you can use a `@JoinTable` annotation.

You don't need the `Friend` class. You can deal with `friends` with `HQL` or `Criteria`. So you don't need to know about a join table. Hibernate will add joins for a join table while converting `HQL` to `SQL`.

`from Student s inner join fetch s.friends where s.name = :studentName`

Keep in mind that it is `HQL`, for `JPQL` you need `select`.

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 35)        
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Student> friends = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Student> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public void setFriends(List<Student> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am testing now.

Comment: There isn't any association between Friend and Student class? This is my query to find all finds of "John":  SELECT S2.name FROM Student S1 JOIN Friend F on S1.id = F.id_from JOIN Student S2 on S2.id = F.id_to WHERE S1.name = "John";

Comment: Without association between Student and Friend, how do I know (map) the "id_from" and "id_to" in Friend class to student ID?

Comment: So all friends are stored in memory, that may be too much for a little big data. I think an explicit table may be needed to store the relationship.

Comment: I am confused. Besides efficiency, without persisting the friends, how do you know what friends a particular Student has for a particular search?

Comment: @user697911 Friends don't store in memory. An explicit table will be generated by Hibernate automatically. _how do you know what friends a particular Student has for a particular search?_ — see HQL in my answer, it requests a student by a name with his friends.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, to implement a many to many relation you need to use some middle table to map keys from two other tables.

In your case you need, say, `t_students_friends` table with two columns like the following:

### t_students_friends

student_pk | friend_pk

In your entity classes you may need Lists for students and/or friends. Note that `@ManyToMany` also requires a `@JoinTable` annotation to work.
If you want to access friends of a student, add to your `Student` class:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="t_students_friends",
  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_pk", referencedColumnName="id"),
  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="friend_pk", referencedColumnName="id"))
private List<Friend> friends;
```

You should also modify `Friend` class as follows. Add

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="friends")
private List<Student> students;
```

and use simple `@Id int id` field as you do in Students. There is no need in a FriendsPK class.

For more information you can read [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany), for example.

Comment: the tables you suggested may be another design, and I will explore that. But my two-table design seems to work too. On mysql command line, I can do searches like "find all friends of student John", as you can see from the link (mysqlfiddle). Do you think my database design is ok and I only need to figure out how to implement the JPA classes?

Comment: @user697911 I don't think it is good to represent a MTM relation using only two tables. It's considered as bad practice that leads to mess in you database tables, as well as in your java code, because you need to find some bad and complicated custom solutions for a simple problem.

Comment: Phil_g, schema wise, it seems pretty simple, as you can see the structure of the two tables, Student(id, name), and Friendship(id_from, id_to). Why do you think this is complicated? Maybe I am missing something. To me it seems even much simpler than 3-table design.

Comment: `@ManyToMany` is not required to specify `@JoinTable` annotation _to work_.

Comment: @user697911 It is valid to have only two tables in this case, because of we have a relation to the same table (`Student`).

Comment: @v.ladynev, I am having some trouble to create the Friend class. How can I modify it?

Comment: @user697911 I add answer

Comment: @phil_g It is not need to create an association between a `Student` and a `Friend` table, because of friends the same students.